# Spring static initialization of a bean

Tags: spring, static, static-initialization

Hey,
how one should deal with static initializations in Spring ? I mean, my bean has a static initialization

```
private static final Map<String, String> exceptionMapping = ErrorExceptionMapping.getExceptionMapping();
```

And I need to take care that ErrorExceptionMapping is loaded before. I tried this:

```
<bean id="errorExceptionMapping" class="cz.instance.transl.util.ErrorExceptionMapping" />
<bean id="validateService" class="cz.instance.transl.services.ValidateService" depends-on="errorExceptionMapping" >
```

But I got

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class cz.instance.transl.util.ErrorExceptionMapping
```

If I omit the static initialization or call the method from within the bean's method, its of course fine. I suppose that Initialization callback (affterPropertiesSet()) wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having `static` dependencies on other beans is not a Spring way.

However, if you want to keep it `static`, you can initialize it lazily - in that case `depends-on` can enforce proper initialization order.

**EDIT:** By lazy loading I mean something like this (I use lazy initialization with holder class idiom here, other lazy initialization idioms can be used instead):

```
private static class ExceptionMappingHolder {
    private static final Map<String, String> exceptionMapping = 
        ErrorExceptionMapping.getExceptionMapping(); 
}
```

and use `ExceptionMappingHolder.exceptionMapping` instead of `exceptionMapping`.

Comment: I tried, look at the pasted code in the middle, but it gives me NoClassDefFoundError for the class. In this class there are tons of other classes I'd have to declare...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to mark the class with the `@Component` annotation, then add a non static setter with `@Autowired(required=true)` annotation for setting the static variable.

[Here's a link](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105) for more info.

Comment: I suppose that would work, but I'm initializing a HashMap, so it's complicated. I better do some refactoring and do it in the spring way, it is singleton anyway, thank you